# Lubuntu-desktop doesn't allow resizing and moving of windows

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

My ubuntu recently became laggy and couldn't figure out why . So i installed Lubuntu-desktop on it, which works fine now . But resizing or moving smaller windows doesn't work . most application don't even have close or fullscreen options on top right. it uses lxqt0.14.1. i tried pressing alt and other keys .

Comment: Please provide OS & especially release details. (my guess is *focal* or 20.04, but it's best if we're not guessing).  Have you logged into the Lubuntu or LXQt session (LXQt session has many Lubuntu scripts disabled, meaning you may need to define functions, as Lubuntu uses openbox for many functions LXQt doesn't actually have defined.. so the LXQt session will not perform those functions until you've set them up; using the Lubuntu session gets all Lubuntu's setup)

Comment: Thnxx for replying. its 20.04 and yes i have logged into lubuntu not lxqt

Comment: What function i need to define I need to resize my windows and move them.

Comment: I would check your appearance settings (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html) and also your openbox preferences (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.11/openbox_settings.html)  You mention *most applications* which makes me think it maybe GTK or Qt applications that are good, the other is your problem. Have you picked a compatible GTK & Qt theme, or was your GTK theme chosen in your prior setup?  Openbox preferences will control the close/minimize/rollup/maximize settings (except for applications that ignore settings using preset defaults)

Comment: I have tried these settings it doesn't work. My theme is lubuntu arc-darker. chrome and a few other does have minimise quit buttons on top right other application doesn't even have border . but even in chrome when i click resize it still cover full screen.